# Vue JS: window.location alternate in SSR

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, quasar-framework

I am building an SSR app in Quasar Vue. The app needs to store `window.location` in a store to send to the API server. For example: if my ssr frontend is running at URL http://localhost:8080, i want to extract localhost:8080.

But since `window` is a browser side utility, it generates an error in SSR mode. Is there any alternate that I can use to get the url of the client.

Comment: Can't you just skip that part of the code since it probably isn't necessary for SSR? Once hydrated the functionality will work again. `if(typeof window === 'undefined') return;`

Comment: I am making a request to an external API on the server-side, and I need to send the window.location value with the API request. 

Will this solution work in such scenario?

Comment: @AhmedRaza did you find any solution?